# Request device admin permissions from user via React Native app native module?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am trying to add device admin features in React Native app. I created a simple native module which have the following react method which is called from JS stack:

```
@ReactMethod
public void requestAdmin(Promise promise) {
    ComponentName deviceAdminComponentName = new ComponentName(context, SecureDeviceAdminReciever.class);
    if(!isDeviceAdmin(context, deviceAdminComponentName)) {
        context.runOnUiQueueThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestAdminIntent();
                promise.resolve(true);
            }
        });

    }
}

public void requestAdminIntent() {
    ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getCurrentActivity().getApplicationContext(), DeviceAdminRequestActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.runOnUiQueueThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            context.startActivityForResult(intent, DeviceAdminRequestActivity.REQUEST_DEVICE_ADMIN_PERMISSIONS,null);
        }
    });

}
```

In the above code I am calling a custom activity which I had to create since `DeviceAdminAdd` activity will not work with with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` after revising code here and react-native requires it:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/marshmallow-dev/src/com/android/settings/DeviceAdminAdd.java

So inside the custom activity inside `onCreate`, I have the following implementation to execute `DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN` intent:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    ComponentName deviceAdminComponentName = null;
    deviceAdminComponentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SecureDeviceAdminReciever.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdminComponentName);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Note: The permissions granted by you is used for applying the anti-theft features.");
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.d("Device Admin Request", "Requested to start action add device admin ... ");
}
```

My policies xml file `@xml/device_admin_policies.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <disable-camera />
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

And manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DeviceAdminRequestActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".PowerStateReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".SecureAdminReciever"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_policies" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.admin.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.admin.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now the issue I am having is that I am getting a blank activity to show up but its not showing up the device admin dialog to activate device admin for app. I set a breakpoint at `startActivity(intent)` line inside `onCreate()` for debugging it turns out that it executes `startActivity(intent)` and right after that it shows a blank activity but not device admin dialog. I will appreciate anyone who can help or have idea why this is happening.